# Get User's IP Address in a Share Point Web Part not giving valid IP address

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

This code in a standard custom WebPart:

```
private string GetUserIP()
{
     return Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] ?? Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```

}

is returning: `"fe80::c564:7922:d873:5cf5%11"` instead of a valid IP address. It does this for every method I've found on Google for retrieving it, including HttpRequest.UserHostAddress.

Does anyone have an idea what is going on?

**Edit:** For some reason it's giving me IPv6 when loading the page locally, but works as intended when I access from a different machine :/

Comment: That *is* a valid IP-address. IPv6.

Comment: @J. Steen: You are correct. For some reason on my development server it is returning the IPv6 IP instead of IPv4. It works when I access the same server remotely...

Answer (score -1):

Use this,

```
string ip = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ip))
{
    ip = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
}
```

Or use

```
string ipAddress = Request.UserHostAddress
```

Comment: That's... basically the same code, except it also checks for empty strings. It doesn't change the fact that OP is getting an IPv6 address, when they obviously want an IPv4 one.

Comment: `Request.UserHostAddress` is identical to `Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]`.